# Bootstrap 4 multiselect dropdown can't show selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to create a multi-select dropdown but when I choose a value, the input field didn't show the value that I selected.

I want something like this:

[image: i want something like this:]

here my code result before I selected the value:

[image: before selected value:]

after selected value:

[image: after selected value:]

here is the console after I selected the value:

[image: here is the console after I selected value:]

here is the error at line 1642 from the console:

[image: here is the error at line 1642 from console:]

here is my input code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-6">
      <select class="multipleselect tags" name="id_tag[]" data-width="100%" data-live-search="true" multiple>
          <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) : ?>
              <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></option>
          <?php endfor; ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm using these plugins:
[bootstrap-select-1.13.18](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.13.18)

bootstrap version v4.5.0 and jquery 3.5.1

any solution?
sorry for the bad English and bad thread.

Comment: find which button in javascript is `buttonInner` and try to find it

Comment: can you show your jquery code ?

Comment: @Swati i only using this code at my jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.multipleselect').selectpicker();
 });
</script>

Comment: Hi is this `mutliselect` or `selectpicker` ?

Comment: i'm tryin to create `multiselect`